# mypy: Can you specify that a Python function takes a list of a single type, but that type can be any type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

I'm trying to write a type annotation for the following function (Python 3.9.7):

```
def first(the_list):
    return the_list[0]
```

This should accept a list of any single type, and return a member of that type. As I understand it, you'd do that like this:

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

def first(the_list : list[T]) -> T:
    return the_list[0]
```

I'm testing this with the following:

```
print(first([2,3,4]))            # Fine
print(first(["hello", "world"])) # Fine
print(first(["hello", 5]))       # This should error
```

running mypy (0.910) like this:

```
mypy --strict .
```

and the result I get is this:

> Success: no issues found in 1 source file

I've made sure that it is running on the correct file, I can definitely get errors, but I'm not getting an error in this case. Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1):

After further investigation (using `reveal_type` which I forgot existed), of course `["hello", 5]` is passed as a list of a single type, that type is `object`.

I'm new to mypy but have studied typing and types at university, so I had a certain expectation for how it was going to work. When I discovered that this example seemed "broken" I was worried that maybe I shouldn't continue with mypy. On reflection, this is a very contrived example, and doesn't indicate that mypy Generics in general are weak, but just demonstrates how they behave when passed a literal whose most restricted type is `list[object]`.

Comment: This is why you should use specifically annotated types for these sorts of demonstrations. Yes, this doesn't reflect at all on Python's generics, this is merely the result of the type inference rules for literal expressions. Next time use `mylist: Union[str, int] = whatever` then pass `mylist` to the function